# Who will create WADL file in Application based on JERSY 2.0

Tags: rest, weblogic, jersey-2.0, wadl

As i am automatically able to access the WADL file for my application without doing any manual effort, through below formatted URL:

```
http://{host}:{port}/{context_root}/{resource}/application.wadl
```

But now need to know, how this will be generated, I am using `jersy 2.0` API over `Weblogic Server` for REST implementation.

If it is automatically generated then what environment and API needed for this ?

Some wiki Or docs URL will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this from the Jersey Documentation, which seems to be responsible for the WADL Generation.

> 17.2. Configuration
>
> WADL generation is enabled in Jersey by default. This means that
>   OPTIONS methods are added by default to each resource and an
>   auto-generated /application.wadl resource is deployed too. To override
>   this default behavior and disable WADL generation in Jersey, setup the
>   configuration property in your application:
>
> jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl=true
>
> This property can be setup in a web.xml if the Jersey application is
>   deployed in the servlet with web.xml or the property can be returned
>   from the Application. getProperties(). See Deployment chapter for more
>   information on setting the application configuration properties in
>   various deployments.
>
> WADL support in Jersey is implemented via ModelProcessor extension.
>   This implementation enhances the application resource model by adding
>   the WADL providing resources. WADL ModelProcessor priority value is
>   high (i.e. the priority is low) as it should be executed as one of the
>   last model processors. Therefore, any ModelProcessor executed before
>   will not see WADL extensions in the resource model. WADL handling
>   resource model extensions (resources and OPTIONS resource methods) are
>   not added to the application resource model if there is already a
>   matching resource or a resource method detected in the model. In other
>   words, if you define for example your own OPTIONS method that would
>   produce "application.wadl" response content, this method will not be
>   overridden by WADL model processor. See Resource builder chapter for
>   more information on ModelProcessor extension mechanism.

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/wadl.html#d0e13189

Answer (score 0):

You can check in Weblogic documentation as well:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/develop.htm#RESTF240